# python - find objects in a custom list that are equal based on custom function

Tags: python, list, filter, reduce

Here is my code :

```
>>> class MyClass() :
...      def __init__( self, item ) :
...              self.a = item["a"]
...              self.b = item["b"]
...      def __eq__(self, other ) :
...              return self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b
...      def myEqualityFunc(self,other) :
...              return self.b == other.b
...      def __str__(self) :
...              return str( self.__dict__ )
...
>>> t1 = MyClass({"a" : ["X1"] , "b" : [1,2] })
>>> t2 = MyClass({"a" : ["X2"] , "b" : [1,2] })
>>> t3 = MyClass({"a" : ["Y1"] , "b" : [3] })
>>>
>>> l = [t1,t3,t2 ]
>>> for l_ in l :
...     print l_
...
{'a': ['X1'], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': ['Y1'], 'b': [3]}
{'a': ['X2'], 'b': [1, 2]}
```

What I am trying to do is find the objects in my list that are equal based on `myEqualityFunc` -> in my example these will be t1 and t2 since they have the same `b` attribute.

I know that `a` is unique.

Is there a more pythonic way than that :

```
for outer_l in l:
    for inner_l in l :
            if outer_l.myEqualityFunc( inner_l ) and outer_l != inner_l :
               # remove inner_l from l since found and keep it in anotehr data structure.
```

Ultimate goal is to end up with something like this but right now I am doing it in more than one steps :

```
>>> for r in result :
...     print r
...
{'a': ['X1' , 'X2'], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': ['Y1'], 'b': [3]}
```

Comment: double list comprehension which filters?

Answer (score 0):

First, definitely check what [itertools library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) does.

Second, you can use `itertools.combinations` in this case.

```
import itertools
map(your_func_to_do_stuff_with_pairs, itertools.combinations(l, 2))
```

Here `your_func_to_do_stuff_with_pairs` looks like

```
def your_func_to_do_stuff_with_pairs(pair):
    # do sth with pair[0] and pair[1]
    if pair[0].myEqualityFunc( pair[1]) and pair[0] != pair[1] :
          # what happens when if is satisfied
```

Answer (score 0):

> find objects in a custom list that are equal based on custom function

This is exactly what `groupby` was made for

```
t1 = MyClass({"a" : ["X1"] , "b" : [1,2] })                                     
t2 = MyClass({"a" : ["X2"] , "b" : [1,2] })                                     
t3 = MyClass({"a" : ["Y1"] , "b" : [3] })                                       

l = [t1,t3,t2]                                                                  

data = sorted(l, key = lambda t: t.b)                                           
for k, g in itertools.groupby(data, lambda t: t.b):                             
    print("key =", k)                                                           
    for t in g: print(t)
```

Output:

```
key = [1, 2]
{'a': ['X1'], 'b': [1, 2]}
{'a': ['X2'], 'b': [1, 2]}
key = [3]
{'a': ['Y1'], 'b': [3]}
```

Comment: much cleaner answer than mine. I didn't know about groupby (outside pandas), so good